# Get Total Storage Quota in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am fairly new to SharePoint 2013 and am trying to display the Storage Quota on my web page but I cannot find any property for it. I have looked up in the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UsageInfo class but the storage property in that gives me only the bytes that have been currently used up by the site collection. Does anyone know how to get the total Storage Quota in SharePoint 2013?